# Failed Flutter launch on M1 Pro Mac: 'WebRTC/WebRTC.h' file not found

Tags: ios, flutter, apple-m1

Another try (because there is literally no answer for my problem so far – and I tried everything):

I installed Flutter with its newest version 2.5.3–stable & so on... On my new M1 MacBook Pro 2021. When I finally started the app via iOS simulator, I got following error:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 12 Pro in debug mode...
lib/main.dart:1
Xcode build done.                                            7,3s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    --- xcodebuild: WARNING: Using the first of multiple matching destinations:
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:dvtdevice-DVTiOSDeviceSimulatorPlaceholder-iphonesimulator:placeholder, name:Any iOS Simulator Device }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:96695B31-48A1-4B31-8BEA-51E02540A81A, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 8 }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:D4D23FEB-B941-4CB1-BFE8-9C643E79477E, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 8 Plus }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:B56FF08E-B7F5-4BFB-9F01-75E41807A1F9, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 11 }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:B3DDBDA9-3D40-4720-A257-FC4956EFDD64, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 11 Pro }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:43FC4F2B-CCA9-4AD5-A4A5-EA821B9485F0, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 11 Pro Max }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:90DA06FB-9E4E-44FC-87A1-CB2B29E79E38, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 12 }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:DED818A9-1360-49FD-B6F6-DB6CC2F09507, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 12 Pro }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:DF07441D-3EDC-4753-A1E2-B6E6E53D5173, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 12 Pro Max }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:4E451889-D81E-4264-9A49-2B5BC960B6E4, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 12 mini }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:82049BCE-9537-4695-8FEB-A9330136D785, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 13 }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:133CF198-FA8B-4902-9869-9ACFAA692DAC, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 13 Pro }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:505D5870-7D81-45C5-BAD1-916BACA40597, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 13 Pro Max }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:CDF40B6D-DC1E-45C5-A17C-566E3DA43C36, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 13 mini }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:84FA02DF-9E7B-453C-BFA1-C4EF496CD94B, OS:15.0, name:iPhone SE (2nd generation) }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:EB2487B7-4688-4FC9-A5F4-2171FD926C90, OS:15.0, name:iPod touch (7th generation) }
    { platform:macOS, arch:arm64, variant:Designed for [iPad,iPhone], id:00006000-000469540A06801E }
    { platform:iOS, id:dvtdevice-DVTiPhonePlaceholder-iphoneos:placeholder, name:Any iOS Device }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:49577F1C-50C7-4C7D-97A2-E455E630A5F5, OS:15.0, name:iPad (9th generation) }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:AC7E2C7F-A654-4FCA-8548-A676B217A1F4, OS:15.0, name:iPad Air (4th generation) }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:A4A2531A-F835-48EC-8426-574FDECA2D29, OS:15.0, name:iPad Pro (9.7-inch) }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:1943D536-50F1-4D93-96E8-0CAE5C676CE6, OS:15.0, name:iPad Pro (11-inch) (3rd generation) }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:91027BFD-9B5A-4ED0-9213-88A969D0479E, OS:15.0, name:iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (5th generation) }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:AEAB67B7-15D0-47DD-A571-BDFF90B73982, OS:15.0, name:iPad mini (6th generation) }
    ** BUILD FAILED **
Xcode's output:
↳
/Users/janhecker/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_webrtc-0.7.1/ios/Classes/FlutterRTCMediaStream.m:3:9: fatal error: 'WebRTC/WebRTC.h' file not found
    #import <WebRTC/WebRTC.h>
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    1 error generated.
    note: Using new build system
    note: Planning
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Podfile: https://www.toptal.com/developers/hastebin/wijiyumiqo.rb

Comment: I would like to help! But this seems a device related problem. Is there a way we could connect?